# On a $\epsilon$-$n$ proof of a limit of a sequence of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, epsilon-delta

Put $\delta_n = 2^{-n}$. To each positive integer $n$ and each real number $t$ corresponds a unique integer $k = k_n(t)$ that satisfies $k\delta_n \le t< (k+1) \delta_n$.

Define $$ \psi_n(t) = \begin{cases} k_n(t)\delta_n, & \mbox{if } 0 \le t < n \\ n, & \mbox{if } n \le t \le \infty \end{cases} $$

I want to prove with  $\epsilon$-$n$ that $ \psi_n(t) \rightarrow t$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.
I proceeded as follows:  $$|\psi_n(t) - t|< \epsilon \implies |k_n(t)\delta_n-t|< \epsilon \implies -k_n(t)\delta_n + t< \epsilon \implies -k2^{-n} + t< \epsilon \implies$$
$$+k2^{-n}>+t-\epsilon \implies \log k -n\log2> \log(t-\epsilon) \implies +n<\frac{-\log(t-\epsilon) + \log(k)}{\log2}$$

But checking with some numbers this result shows that not all $n<\frac{-\log(t-\epsilon) + \log k}{\log2}$ work given an $\epsilon$ when plugged into $|k_n(t)\delta_n-t|< \epsilon$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you perhaps edit this to more clearly represent what you're trying to do? I *think* I see what you're doing (that is, $k_n(t)\delta_n$ is just $t$ truncated to its first $n$ bits), but it's a bit hard to work with as it is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof fails because it treats $k$ as if it were constant with $n$. The proof is already off the rails once you get to
$$-k2^{-n}+t<\varepsilon$$
since, from there, you show that this cannot hold for all large enough $n$ - but of *course* it doesn't hold for all large enough $n$, because that would be equivalent to requiring $t<\varepsilon$, as the $-k2^{-n}$ vanishes as $n$ gets large.

Moreover, the proof proceeds in the wrong direction from the start; it's set up to prove:

> If $|\psi_n(t)-t|<\varepsilon$, then $n$ is larger than a constant depending on $\varepsilon$.

But that's not helpful - it could be vacuous, in that $|\psi_n(t)-t|$ could never be less than $\varepsilon$, meaning the implication wouldn't prove anything. What you want to show is that

> If $n$ is larger than some constant depending on $\varepsilon$, then $|\psi_n(t)-t|<\varepsilon$.

To start on that one, notice that if $n>t$, then we have, from the inequality at the start of your post and some substitution: $$\psi_n(t)\leq t < \psi_n(t) + \delta_n$$
which implies that $|\psi_n(t)-t|<2^{-n}$ (and that the same holds for any $n'>n$). Use this to, for any $\varepsilon$, choose a large enough $n$ such that $|\psi_n(t)-t|<2^{-n}$.

Comment: So If I am understanding correctly the correct n is $n > \frac{log\epsilon}{log2}$?  In the future I will edit more clearly, I was imprecise.

Comment: @Monolite Yes, that would work (and was what I had in mind)

Comment: I am unsure that $\psi_n(t)\leq t < \psi_n(t) + \delta_n$ implies $|\psi_n(t)-t|<2^{-n}$.  Wouldn't the addition of the absolute value mess things up?

Comment: @Mello I have an other question, disregarding the fact that $k$ is not constant with $n$ could my way of proceeding by salvaged by substituting the implies with if and only ifs? As to set it up correctly.

Comment: @Mello I realised what happened with the addition of the absolute value.

Comment: Yes, if you used if and only if and ended with $n>\text{something}$, it'd work. I wouldn't really recommend this, since it requires you to prove both directions when you only need one.